# Letter counter II

Tags: python

A couple days ago, I made a program that allowed me to pick a letter from a string and it would tell me how many times a chosen letter appeared. Now I want to use that code to create a program that takes all the letters and counts how many times each letter appears. For example, if I put "dog" in as my string, I would want the program to say that d appears once, o appears once, and g appears once. Here is my current code below.

```
from collections import Counter
import string
pickedletter= ()
count = 0
word = ()


def count_letters(word):
    global count
    wordsList = word.split()
    for words in wordsList:
        if words == pickedletter:
            count = count+1
    return count

word = input("what do you want to type? ")
pickedletter = input("what letter do you want to pick? ")
print (word.count(pickedletter))
```

Comment: Okay great. So what is your question?

Comment: It's like you Googled and found all the pieces, now you just want us to solve the puzzle...

Comment: the question is i'm wondering how to count how many times every letter present appears in the code

Comment: Not pertinent to the question, but why are you both declaring `count` as a global variable and returning it from your function?

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter

def count_letters(word):
    counts = Counter(word)
    for char in sorted(counts):
        print char, "appears", counts[char], "times in", word
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't see why he imports `Counter` but doesn't use it.

Comment: He uses it. First line of function

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're importing anything for this, especially `Counter`.  This is the approach I would use:

```
def count_letters(s):
    """Count the number of times each letter appears in the provided
    specified string.

    """

    results = {}  # Results dictionary.
    for x in s:
        if x.isalpha():
            try:
                results[x.lower()] += 1  # Case insensitive.
            except KeyError:
                results[x.lower()] = 1
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and the cow jumps over the moon.'
    results = count_letters(s)
    print(results)
```